# Using the J option for REPL.BAT

Tags: batch-file, replace, store, batch-processing

I'm trying to use the REPL.BAT script with the new 'J' option, which allows for JScript expressions for replace arguments.  This script was created by @dbenham (original REPL.BAT [post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855)  and earliest StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir/16735079#16735079)).  I'm having some difficulty with the syntax and was hoping to get some help. Here's an example of the scenario.

I have the following line of code:

```
"Port #" == driver.find_element_by_id("portno").text: break
```

I would like to replace the line of code above with the following:

```
expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'portno'), "Port #")
```

As you can see, the original line of code has a lowercase 'id' while the code I'd like to replace it with has an uppercase 'ID'.  I've tried using the following to replace the line:

```
type %iFile% | 
repl "\b(.*?) \=\= driver\.find_element_by_(.*?)\(\q(.*?)\q\)\.text\: break" 
"expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.$2.toUpperCase(), '$3'), $1)"
JMX >filenameNEW.py
```

Whenever I attempt this, I receive a "JScript runtime error: Invalid character" error.  I tried changing the...

```
$2.toUpperCase()
```

...to...

```
$[2].toUpperCase()
```

...but receive the same error I stated in the last sentence.  Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly?  Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem have several details; first the simplest ones:

- You missed to include the J option!
- When you not use J option, the replacement string is a *literal* that will just change the $1, $2,... values; for example: **"This value: $1"**. When you use J option, the replacement string is *a JScript **expression*** that must be assembled in the right way; for example: **"'This value: '+$1"**, that is, the replacement string is the literal 'This value: ' joined (+) with the value of $1 (submatched substring). This way, you must rewrite the complete replacement string as a JScript expression.

Now a single funny point:

- In the expression you may use apostrophes to enclose literal strings, and you can NOT use quotes because they terminate the parameter of REPL.BAT. I thought at first that an apostrophe could be included as a special character via its \x27 hexa code, but for a strange reason it doesn't work, so I have to "disguise" the apostrophe via fromCharCode() function. **NOTE**: I used my FindRepl.bat program in my tests, so I don't know if dbenham's REPL.BAT behave in the same way in this point.

And a final point:

- In the first part of your regexp: \b(... the \b indicate "start of word", but a word start at the first *letter*, so the quotes are left outside of the subexpression! I changed this part by "\s+(.*) ...", that is, skip spaces and start the subexpression at the first non-space character, that include the quotes.

Wow! Here it is; as I said, I used FindRepl.bat program, but I think this work the same way in REPL.BAT:

```
@echo off
set line=  "Port #" == driver.find_element_by_id("portno").text: break
echo Input:
echo %line%

echo Wanted:
echo expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'portno'), "Port #")
echo/

echo %line%| "FindRepl Modified.bat" "\s+(.*) \=\= driver\.find_element_by_(.*?)\(\q(.*?)\q\)\.text\: break" 
"Apos=String.fromCharCode(39),'expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.'+$2.toUpperCase()+', '+Apos+$3+Apos+'), '+$1+')'" /J /Q:q
```

Output:

```
expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'portno'), "Port #")
```

You may try to eliminate Apos variable and use \x27 to insert an apostrophe *inside a literal string enclosed in apostrophes*. I'll appreciate it if you post the result of this change...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Aacini.  Yes, I did forget to include my options, which is a big deal in determining the correct syntax; my apologies!  As you'll see above, I'm trying to use the 'J' option along with the 'M' and 'X' option.  I do believe this is why I'm having difficulty.  The 'M' option allows me to do a REPL for multiple lines at once while the 'X' option allows for extended substitution within the REPLACE string.  If I take away the **.toUpperCase()** portion as well as the 'J' option, the code works fine except 'id' will be lowercase instead of capitalized.

Comment: Also, looking at @dbenham's example at the [site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37855#p37855), he doesn't appear to use **+$1** in his examples.

Comment: Sleeping on this and coming back to it did me some good.  I understand your explanation now.  I created a small script to reproduce this issue on a small scale first & was able to get that to work properly.  I believe I can attempt this on a much larger scale now.  Thank you for your time and help @Aacini!

Comment: Can an apostrophe be directly included in the JScript expression via `\x27` in REPL.BAT program? Or it requires also the "Apos" trick...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to get back to you about that, @Aacini.  Yes, \x27 works fine in REPL.BAT (Ver. 6.2) and produces the desired apostrophe.  Double quotes, of course, did not work, so that did require your "Apos" trick.